# Ghost: Get URL of post in foreach loop

Tags: ghost-blog

I'm looking to get the URL of a post accessed using a `{{#foreach posts}}{{/foreach}}` helper. The structure I am using right now is :

```
            <div class="pfdflxbx">            
                {{#get "posts" limit="3" include="tags, authors" filter="featured:true"}}
                    {{#foreach posts limit="3"}}
                        {{title}}
                    {{/foreach}}
                {{/get}}
            </div>
```

When I insert a `{{url}}` helper between `{{title}}` and `{{/foreach}}`, the URL that gets returned to me is the url of the site's home page.

If I use the following structure:

```
            <div class="pfdflxbx">            
                {{#get "posts" limit="3" include="tags, authors" filter="featured:true"}}
                    {{#foreach posts limit="3"}}
                    {{#post}}
                        {{title}}
                    {{/post}}
                    {{/foreach}}
                {{/get}}
            </div>
```

Nothing renders to the DOM, as in, no posts populate.

Could someone help shed some light on the correct practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution I posted was correct. There is a bug in the back end version I am working with which causes the URL of the blog posts to redirect to the welcome page.